# How do I fix mismatched stained, stamped concrete?

Tags: concrete, staining

I have a stained concrete walkway surrounding my newly built house. The problem is that right in front of the entrance the walkway changes color. The builder did the project at 2 different times and now he is telling me that he cannot correct this so that it is 1 color.

I’m not fussy about the color, I just want it to be consistent. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: Paint.  Was the concrete or the stain at different times?  About the only way to make the stain one colour/shade is to go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

If you're after a uniform color for pigmented concrete, then it can't be done. For the stains that you can still use to alter the color, the low spots of the stamped concrete attract extra stain and get more intense coloring. The darker colored low spots can be attractive in my opinion, but in the pigmented concrete case, that wasn't your intended design.

If it was stained after placing the concrete and has darker color in the low spots of the stamped concrete, then I imagine that you could dilute an acid stain, mask off the darker part, and stain the light part for a better match. I can also imagine getting into an endless loop of "fixing" one part and then the other until settling for a darker mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that the builder CAN'T fix it, he just doesn't want to because it would involve tearing it all out and redoing the whole sidewalk in one pour/stamp/stain.  That's potentially a lot of cost/effort for him, so obviously he doesn't want to.  Hopefully it's still under warranty, and I'd think that it should be covered under that.  Stained concrete will be almost impossible to match if done in separate sections, hence the situation you're in now.

Comment: Good luck getting the warranty to cover that.